# Divide an array into subarray depending on string and join its items. Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, join, reduce

I would like to transform an array into another separing its items depending on a string data, and, when there are two or more items together and none of them is is the limit string data i would like to join then by "/". Something like this:

`const stringLimit = "aa";`
`let arrayData =["b","c","aa","aa","d","c","aa","f"];`

result:

`arrayResult=["b/c","d/c","f];`

I have try this, however, I think that there should be a better way

```
let stringItem;
let totalRouteDevice = new Array();
for (let index = 0; index < arrayData.length; index++) {
    const item = arrayData [index];
    if(item!=='aa' && item !== 'bb') {
      stringItem = stringItem!=""?`${stringItem}/${item}`:stringItem
    } else if(stringRouteItem!=="") {
      totalRoute.push(stringItem);
      stringItem ="";
    }
}
```

I have try this, however, I think that there should be a better way

```
let stringItem;
let totalRouteDevice = new Array();
for (let index = 0; index < arrayData.length; index++) {
    const item = arrayData [index];
    if(item!=='aa' && item !== 'bb') {
      stringItem = stringItem!=""?`${stringItem}/${item}`:stringItem
    } else if(stringRouteItem!=="") {
      totalRoute.push(stringItem);
      stringItem ="";
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi kiusy, welcome to StackOverflow. What have you tried to solve your problem?

Comment: i have try the following:

Answer (score 1):

Not saying this is better but you could group your data using reduce, splitting it by `stringLimit`, and then joining the groups by `/` as follows:

```js
const stringLimit = 'aa'

const arrayData = ["b","c","aa","aa","d","c","aa","f"]

let arr = []

arrayData.reduce((acc, item, i) => {
  if (item !== stringLimit) {
    acc.push(item)
  } else {
    if (acc.length) {
      arr.push(acc)
    }
    acc = []
  }

  if (item !== stringLimit && i === arrayData.length - 1) {
    arr.push(acc)
  }

  return acc
}, [])

let result = arr.map((i) => i.join('/'))

console.log(result)
```